# Deadlock на Apache

Tags: mysql, sql, apache, nginx

Добрый вечер. 
Назрел следущий вопрос:
Apache обслуживает в один момент только 1 соединение, тоесть следущий посетитель ждет пока посетитель перед ним завершит соединение с сервером.
Nginx может одновременно обслуживать 10к+ соединений.

Отсюда напрашивается вопрос, как на Апаче может возникнуть дедлок в БД, если клиенты обслуживаются в порядке очереди а не одновременно?

Comment: Кривые руки могут всё! Поясните, как вы Apach'ем работаете с БД?

Comment: Apache работает на mod_php, который делает запрос в БД. Затем Apache возвращает html разметку с данными из БД клиенту. Тоесть в один момент времени только один человек работает с БД. Значит и дедлок возникнуть не может. Или я чего то не понимаю?

Comment: Как вы определили что происходит deadlock?

Comment: На практике это не воспроизводил.

Comment: Откуда вы взяли информацию, что apache обслуживает одновременно только одно соединение ? web-сервер, обслуживающий одновременно только одно подключение невозможно было бы использовать. И разумеется апач одновременно обслуживает много подключений

Comment: Отсюда: http://joxi.ru/J2bNQyvuXDzk42 Если я не правильно понимание написаное то просьба объяснить...

Comment: Кол-во процессов настраивается. И под один сервер могут работать десятки тысяч процессов.

Comment: Да, в апаче просто процессов много делается. это конечно дорого. но если у вас работа с БД значит запускаются какие то cgi. хотя бы тот же php. если cgi обслуживает nginx у него абсолютно та же проблема. у него запущенно n-ое кол-во воркеров обслуживающих php. но один интерпретатор php одновременно может обслуживать одного клиента. все замечания касающиеся скорости nginx касаются обслуживания статических запросов, но ни как не динамических, которые будут работать с БД. И в обоих web-серверах поддерживается много соединений, просто немного разными способами (для статики)

Comment: По поводу одновременного подключения к Апачу понял, спасибо. По поводу пхп - тоесть например у нас 5 одновременных запросов и пхп интерптетатор будет обслуживать их в порядке очереди? Но ведь у нас из пхп делаются запросы к БД и запросы тоже выходит делаются в порядке очереди каждого клиента? И если да то тогда все тот же вопрос, как может появится дедлок?

Comment: Нет, вы не поняли. цитата из предыдущего комента : "_у него запущенно n-ое кол-во воркеров обслуживающих php_". одновременно работают несколько php интерпретаторов, обращения в БД идут параллельно. Только при правильно построенном приложении deadlock все равно не будет. deadlock могут возникать только в случае если приложение в разном порядке блокирует одни и те же ресурсы. надо еще постараться что бы написать настолько криво. Обычно возникают обычные блокировки, когда другие клиенты ожидают действий одного, но это не deadlock, первый клиент доделывает работу, начинает следующий

Comment: Благодорю что объяснили.